# searching for a WSDL or updated xml with finance information

Tags: xml, service, wsdl, finance

i have to create a line chart with finance information like the one in this site http://finance.yahoo.com/

but i need information of all the countries is there a place where i can get this information updated as a web service or xml ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you referring to market index data of the various stock exchanges? ( DOW, TSE, NASDAQ, etc? )

Regardless, this is probably a good start in your search. 
[ProgrammableWeb](http://www.programmableweb.com/apis)

Comment: yea exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Mergent Historical Securities Data API at http://www.mergent.com/servius